# アカウントマージの確認メールが英語のままになっている

Tags: バグ, 翻訳, 英語

先ほどアカウントをマージしたところ、マージメールが英語まじりでした。

> We received your request to merge the following スタック・オーバーフロー accounts:
>
> <アカウント２つのURL>
>
> Before we can merge, we need to confirm that you own both of these accounts. To confirm ownership of <アカウント名>, click the link below:
>
> <マージ用のURL>
>
> We have sent an identical email to confirm ownership of your other account. You have 48 hours to click the links in both emails. Once you do, you'll be presented with the option to merge accounts.
>
> If you didn't receive the other email, or are having any other merge problems, go to our contact form and select 'Other'. If you have changed your mind about the merge or are receiving this email by mistake, feel free to ignore it.

日本語にするとこんな感じになりますが、いかがでしょうか。

> このメールが送られているという事は、以下のスタック・オーバーフローのアカウントをマージしようとしているという事です。
>
> <アカウント２つのURL>
>
> <※この辺りの順番は意図して変更しています。>
>   もし片方は自分じゃないとかアカウントの乗っ取りだとか思うようであればリンクをクリックしないでください。４８時間以内に双方のURLがクリックされない限りアカウントはマージされません。
>
> 「大丈夫だ、問題ない」という人は<アカウント名>の所有権を確認するため以下のリンクをクリックしてください。
>
> <マージ用のURL>
>
> このメールはマージしようとしているアカウント両方に送信しています。
>   再度言いますが、４８時間以内に双方のURLがクリックされない限りアカウントはマージされません。
>   あなたがその片方のメールを受け取っていない、または任意の他のマージ問題がある場合は、このフォームからお問い合わせください。

Comment: メールの件名は日本語になっていましたか？

Comment: @unalist 件名は『Please complete your スタック・オーバーフロー account marge』でした。

Comment: メモ： https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289896?comment=%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB%E9%80%81%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB

Answer (score 1):

もう少し単純？な訳も挙げてみます。アカウント乗っ取りとかにも言及した方がいいんですかね・・・。

> 件名： $siteName$ のアカウントマージの確認 ($part$/2)
>
> スタック・オーバーフローでお使いの以下のアカウントをマージしようとしています：
>
> <アカウント２つのURL>
>
> あなたがアカウント [<アカウント名>](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) の所有者であり、マージに同意する場合は次のリンクをクリックしてください。
>
> <マージ用のURL>
>
> 同様のメールをもう一方のアカウントにも送信しています。両方のメールに書かれたリンクを48時間以内にクリックすると、マージの手続きを進めることができます。
>
> もう一方のメールを受信できない場合、あるいは他に困ったことがあれば、[お問い合わせフォーム](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)で「その他」を選択してお知らせください。身に覚えがない、またはマージを中止する場合は、リンクをクリックせずにこのメールを破棄してください。